# How to set an Android-X custom preference height?

Tags: android, androidx, android-preferences

I am trying to create a custom preference used in a fragment. That preference will have an icon, a long text and a hyperlink to link somewhere.

For that I create a class that extends androidx.preference.Preference

The constructor is this:

```
public MyCustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.my_custom_preference_layout);
}
```

I get it to work correctly and all that, but the problem is that its height is way too short. The preference size doesn't fit its content. It seems like it is always the same size. About two lines of text only.
I have tried with

```
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:minLines="50"
```

but nothing. The preference is displayed way too short.
Is there any limitation in the height of custom preferences?

I use a RelativeLayout for the layout and add the controls I need to it.
that Relative Layout have these values:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I have tried setting match_parent to both, even setting a fixed value, for example 500dp, but it is always displayed in small height.